# Markov models and occupation time

Tags: probability, markov-process, transition-matrix, indicator-function

I'm presented with the following explanation and proof:

> Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain, and fix a state $j \in S$.
>
> Define indicator variables: For $n = 0, 1, \dots$, let
>
> $$I_n(j) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if} \ X_n = j, \\ 0 & \text{if} \ X_n \not= j. \end{cases}$$
>
> $I_n(j) = 1$ says that the MC occupies state $j$ at time $n$.
>
> The probability $I_n(j) = 1$ is $p^{(n)}_{ij}$ if $X_0 = i$.
>
> $I_n (j)$ has a Bernoulli law with parameter $p^{(n)}_{ij}$.
>
> **Lemma 2.** $E(I_n (j) \vert X_0 = i) = p^{(n)}_{ij}$.
>
> Let $N_n (j) = \sum_{m = 0}^n I_m (j), \tag{6}$
>
> $N_n (j)$ is called the *occupation time* of the state $j$ (up to time $n$).
>
> Note that $\sum_{j \in S} N_n (j) = n + 1$.
>
> The mean occupation time of state $j$, given the initial state $i$, is
>
> $$m_{ij}(n) = E(N_n(j) \vert X_0 = i), \ \text{for all} \ i, j \in S.$$
>
> Then $M(n) = (m_{ij}(n))_{ij}$ is called the *mean occupation time matrix*.
>
> **Theorem 3.** The mean occupation time matrix is given by
>
> $$M(n) = \sum_{m = 0}^n \mathcal{P}^m \tag{7}$$
>
> **Proof:** It follows from Lemma 2 and (6) that
>
> $$m_{ij}(n) = \sum_{m = 0}^n E[I_m (j) \vert X_0 = i] = \sum_{m = 0}^n p^{(m)}_{ij}.$$

$\mathcal{P}^n$ is the $n$-step transition matrix.

I am having difficulty understanding the above proof. Specifically, I'm having difficulty understanding how $m_{ij}(n) = \sum_{m = 0}^n E[I_m (j) \vert X_0 = i] = \sum_{m = 0}^n p^{(m)}_{ij}$ follows from Lemma 2 and (6). I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Did you understand Lemma 2 and/or (6) individually?

Comment: @gunes I think so. I think the way in which they come together is what is confusing me. Or it could indeed be that I am not understanding them sufficiently individually, and so that's what's causing me difficulty in understanding them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand Lemma 2 and Equation (6), the rest is just linearity of expectation:

$$\begin{align}m_{ij}(n)&=E[N_n(j)|X_0=i]=E\left[\sum_{m=0}^n I_m(j)\bigg\vert X_0=i\right]=\sum_{m=0}^n E[I_m(j)|X_0=i]\\&=\sum_{m=0}^np_{ij}^{(m)}\end{align}$$

Intuitively, $p_{ij}^{(m)}$ represents how certain we're at $j$-th state at our $m$-th step. If it's $0.1$, we'll be at $j$-th state $0.1$ of the time if we do an experiment, i.e. run the markov chain multiple times. So, summing these expected occupation numbers will yield the mean occupation.

For the simplest case, take all $p_{ij}^{m}=1$, which means the mean occupation is $n+1$ because at every step (out of $n+1$ steps) we're guaranteed to be there.

Comment: Is $m^n_{ij}$ supposed to be $m_{ij}(n)$?

Comment: yes, just changed it.

Comment: So the conditional expected value of a sum is the sum of the conditional expected value? Is this just an application of "pulling out known factors" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties ?

Comment: it’s just linearity of the expectation

Comment: Can you please explain where you got the $n + 1$ from for the mean occupation time?

Comment: If $p_{ij}^{m}=1$, for all $m$, it means you're there every time, like absorbing state. So, you'll be there a total of $n+1$ times, including the initial which is for $m=0$.

Comment: It is all clear to me now. Thank you for taking the time to clarify this.